# Настройка ЧПУ через .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

Здравствуйте! Делаю для одного самописного веб-сайта SEO оптимизацию. На сайте есть товары, лежащие в папке /products/, а конкретный товар, например, /products/product_a/, также есть некое подобие разделов (типа разделение товаров по стилям) /products?style=1, и будут показаны товары, у которых style=1. Лезть в дебри самописоной CMS не очень хочется. Слышал, что есть возможность настроить ЧПУ из htaccess таким образом, чтобы подобные страницы (заранее известные) /products?style=1, /products?style=2, /products?style=3 в URL выглядили как /products/classik/, /products/modern/, /products/wood/ и т.д. При этом в самом движке ничего не меняется. Действительно ли можно настроить такие правила для заранее известных адресов или это миф?

Заранее спасибо!

Создал локальный проект, с одним index.php

```
<?php

switch ($_REQUEST["style"]) {
    case "0": echo "Class\n";
    break;

    case "1": echo "Modern\n";
    break;

    default: echo "not params \n";
}
```

?>

и .htaccess файлом

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/classik/$ /?style=0 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/modern/$ /?style=1 [L,QSA]

модуль mod_rewrite вроде как грузится http://joxi.ru/Z8Y8VIwyTJBfCbo-OFE но почему-то всёравно не работает. Как можно ещё правило прописать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понятно, что значит: «выглядели так». Если подразумевается, что при переходе по адресу, скажем, /products/classik/ загружалась страница /products?style=1, то можно использовать такой код:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/classik$ products?style=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^products/modern$ products?style=2 [L]
```

Или ещё лучше использовать «роутер»: перенаправлять все подобные запросы в один файл, а из него уже подключать файл products.

Comment: Да, именно это и подразумевается, нужно при запросе на /products/classik/ загружать страницу products?style=1. Нашёл в коде такую вот штуку:

public function indexAction() {
  $style = $this->_getParam('style');
  $where = "";
  if ($style !== null)
  {
  $f = new Zend_Filter_Int();
  $style = $f->filter($style);
  $where = ($style !== null) ? "style=$style" : "";
  Zend_Registry::set('cid', 'kitchen_type_'.$style);
  }
  $model = new Kitchen_Model_Item();
  $res = $model->getData($where);
  $this->view->res = $res;
  $this->view->style = $style;
 }
читает style и показывает товары.

Comment: Прописал в .htaccess правило для раздела кухни RewriteRule ^kitchen/klassik$ kitchen?style=1 [L] - к сожалению, не работает. =(

Comment: А сам Rewrite вообще-то работает? По другим параметрам?

Comment: Уже не уверен, буду пробовать.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, дополнение к вопросу, я решил протестировать на локальном хостинге, и что-то тоже на хочет ЧПУ строится.

Comment: На локальном примере разрешилось всё вот таким кодом:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^classik/$ ?style=0 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^modern/$ ?style=1 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 1):

Это не миф.

**update:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^products/classik/$ /products?style=1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^products/modern/$ /products?style=2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^products/wood/$ /products?style=3 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: А может, у кого-то пример завалялся )) Я, честно говоря, не могу найти описания подобного кода, везде идут какие-то общие правила и всё.

Comment: @VenZell, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.